# Is there a more elegant way to print some text then debug::print(&utf8(b"some text printed out")); in Sui move?

Tags: blockchain, move-lang, sui

I'm using the debug module from the std move package in a test function.

```
    use std::debug;

    /* std and sui modules debug tests */
    #[test]
    fun test_module(){
        debug::print(&utf8(b"some text printed out"));
    }
```

What other options do I have to print a text output to the console?
What is the most elegant way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Inside a test, you can do `test_utils::print(b"some text printed out")`

```
use sui::test_utils::{Self};

/* std and sui modules debug tests */
#[test]
fun test_module(){
   test_utils::print(b"some text printed out")
}
```

The test_utils module can be found [here](https://github.com/MystenLabs/sui/blob/testnet-v1.11.1/crates/sui-framework/packages/sui-framework/sources/test/test_utils.move).